# How do I bind one item out of a list within a view model to a controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a view model in ASP.Net Core Razor that has a List of objects called "Venues". I'm trying to send the Reference number and the Formatted Address of one of the venues (out of 20) to a post controller.

The problem is that when I try to, it doesn't bind to the controller method. Here is the controller method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> MeetDetailsVenueChange(string reference, MeetDetailsView mdv)
```

Here's the view model:

```
public class MeetDetailsView
    {

        public string City { get; set; }
        public string RecipientCity { get; set; }
        public string VenueAddress { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public string HostPlaceId { get; set; }
        public string RecipientPlaceId { get; set; }
        public string VenuePlaceId { get; set; }
        public List<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the venue model:

```
public class Venue {
  public int VenueId { get; set; }
        public string Reference { get; set; }
        public string PlaceId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string FormattedAddress { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Rating { get; set; }
        public string PriceLevel { get; set; }
        // Distance between returned location and midpoint.
        public string Distance { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the form:

```
<form asp-action="MeetDetailsVenueChange">
<button type="submit" style="display: block; width: 100%; height:100px;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" value="@Model.Venues[i].FormattedAddress">
<i class="material-icons" style="width:auto; color:white;">
star_border
</i>
</button>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Venues[i]" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="Venues[i]" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Venues[i].FormattedAddress" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="Venues[i].FormattedAddress" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Reference" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="Reference" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

NOTE: This form is in a for loop:

```
      @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Venues.Count(); i++)
        {
...
        }
```

That iterates through every venue in the original view model.
When I set a breakpoint, the keys to the request are:

```
[0] "Venues[1].FormattedAddress"   string
[1] "Reference"                    string
[2] "__RequestVerificationToken"   string
```

At the moment, it only binds to the first Venue selected - I would like it to work for the "ith" model. If I select the button 15 on the list, it should return the values for the 15th on the list. The only thing that is consistently bound is the Reference, and it appears to be so only because the Reference number is not in the list of Venues.

It seems like I would need to be able to bind Venues[0-20].FormattedAddress to the controller method on a post, but I'm not sure why it's only returning the first Venue. The documentation also doesn't have an example of iterating through a collection on a post method, or how to bind a specific object from a collection on a post. I think I have a lack of understanding of how posting in forms works in general beyond individual parameters.

Comment: Are you saying this only works on the 0th item?

Comment: Yes, sorry - only the 0th item is binding

Comment: You need to post just the `Venue` no list, no index. If you attempt a nested list of Venue in `MeetDetailsView`, then you'll need to write the html a bit more manually without the index 0..20, so that each post will have index 0 for the name attribute -- you will be posting a list of one item, always the 0th item.

Comment: I think I understand - but how can I post just the Venue using the same View Model? Will I have to add a SelectedVenue to the View Model, and then bind the values in the form to it?

Comment: I think I may just try a different approach - I have a list of items in a list, and when I click a star on one of them, I want the backend to mark it as the selected item in the list. However, it seems kind of hard to do in ASP.Net so I may just use a Javascript approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jasen for his recommendation - I added the

```
Venue SelectedVenue
```

Parameter to my view model and bound it in the form like this -

```
<form asp-action="MeetDetailsVenueChange">
<button type="submit" style="display: block; width: 100%; height:100px;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" value="@Model.Venues[i].FormattedAddress">
<i class="material-icons" style="width:auto; color:white;">
star_border
</i>
</button>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectedVenue.FormattedAddress" value="@Model.Venues[i].FormattedAddress" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectedVenue.VenueId" value="@Model.Venues[i].VenueId" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectedVenue.PlaceId" value="@Model.Venues[i].PlaceId" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Reference" class="form-control" />
<span asp-validation-for="Reference" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
</form>
```

It works like a charm!
Notice that I specifically use asp-for to bind the part of the model that is the selected item from the list - I sent its value equal to the ith item in the list within the for loop.